# Mutated Array in AngularJS Filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have this custom AngularJS filter containing a few conditions. In my `else` condition I am splicing values out of an array and returning that array.

Here's my issue: Splicing values out of the array in the `else` condition mutates the array, and if the `if` condition is invoked afterwards, it no longer processes the original complete and pristine array, but only a partial array containing the remaining indexes after it's been spliced.

How can I correct this to ensure that I'm working on a **complete** dataset each time the filter is run? I tried working with a copy of the array (using `var newArr = items.splice(0)`)in the `else` block, but for whatever reason the issue remains.

One option is to build a new array in the `else` condition and return that, rather than chipping away at the original array. However since I'm dealing with a complex multi-nested data structure, for simplicity's sake I'm looking for a solution where I can remove values.

```
angular.module("app", []).
filter('department', function() {
  return function(items, args) {
    var filtered;
    var output = [];

    // return all items when 'All Departments' selected              
    if (args.selectedDepartment.Name == 'All Departments' && args.selectedDepartment.Id === undefined) {
      return items;
    }

    // return orders containing products from selected department with 'Inclusive' option
    if (args.selectedDepartment.Id !== undefined && !args.option) {
      for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        filtered = items[i].products.filter(function(item) {
          return item.Order__r.Department__r.Id == args.selectedDepartment.Id;
        });
        if (filtered.length >= 1) {
          output.push(items[i]);
        }
      }

      // return only products which are an exact match to the selected department with 'Exclusive' option
    } else if (args.selectedDepartment.Id !== undefined && args.option) {

      for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < items[i].products.length; j++) {
          if (items[i].products[j].Order__r.Department__r.Id != args.selectedDepartment.Id) {
            items[i].products.splice(j, 1);
          }
        }
        if (items[i].products.length === 0) {
          items.splice(i, 1);
        }
      }

      return items;
    }
    return output;
  };
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing an element from the given array is a mutating operation.

Another approach would be to implement a non-mutating element removal. Instead of directly modifying the input array, the remove function below could return a new array that contains all elements except the specified one:

```
function remove(array, element) {
    return array.filter(e => e !== element);
}
const vowelsAndX = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "x"];
const vowels = remove(vowelsAndX, "x");
vowels.toString(); // "a,e,i,o,u"
```